# Number of PCA varies for same explained variance before and after scaling a dataset

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, scaling, pca

I plotted two scree plot which shows the number of PCA needed to explain certain percentage of the variance. The difference between the two plots are one is before using standard scalar and another is after scaling of the data.I have attached the pictures of both the scree plot.

[image: Number of PCA explains the percentage of variance after scaling]
[image: Number of PCA explains the percentage of variance before scaling]

I will like to know why scaling has this huge amount differences in the number of PCA for a centain explained variance percentage. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your dataset characteristics? If it's not publicly available, can you rerun the experiment with something common e.g. Iris or Breast Cancer dataset?

Comment: The dataset is publicly available. It is a NSL-KDD dataset.

Comment: .And to be on the same page, I will like to add that I have used PCA for the variables which are multi-collinear and their VIF values is above 5. The way it is done is use PCA on the features whose VIF is between 6-10, 11-30,31-100,100-500, above 500.
This way after removing multi-collinearity then I drew those scree plot.